# Form data not POSTing to another page

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am struggling with a problem I have never had before. I have a form on a page that submits its data via POST to another page, but the data is not arriving at the other page. If I make `action=""` and then `var_dump()` at the top of the page with the form, the POST data prints out fine, BUT if I make `action="http://localhost/dir/"` and put `var_dump()` at the top of that page, then `array empty` prints out. What on earth might be causing this behavior? How do I debug this? I'm lost.

Form:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="http://localhost/dir">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="19">
    <select style="width: 60px;" name="number">
        <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="4">4</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" class="input_submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton">
</form>
```

Code at top of index.php file:

```
var_dump($_POST);die();
```

Comment: while experts arrive.. what is the file name where the action is routed? index file?

Comment: @Nate why do you want to put a path like that? Why not just put the file name?

Comment: @itsols - The file is in a different directory.

Comment: @Nate list the directory structure please.

Comment: @Nate try `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`, make sure your action is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To post data to a page that is on a different directory, use a relative path.

For example, consider this. DirSub1 and DirSub2 are in the same level and they're both within DirTop.

- DirTop
- DirSub1
- DirSub2

Now, if your form is in the directory DirSub1 and you need to post it to x.php in DirSub2, you write the action property like this:

**action="../DirSub2/x.php"**

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Hi itsols. I don't want to include the file name in the url, because then the user would see 'x.php' in the url instead of just the directory. Your comments inspired me to start messing around with the URL and I discovered that appending a slash at the end of the action URL results in the data being POSTed, but no slash, no data. Why would that be?

Comment: I'm not sure why in your case, but generally, I presume the slash would indicate the end of a directory and the obvious first thing to look for then is index or main. So this may be the reason why your data got posted with the slash. Perhaps this is configurable on Apache or your web server.

Comment: I what you want to do is not show the interaction with the actual file, you have an easy option. Submit to the same file and then do a server-side redirection to do the processing and then bring the user to a different landing page. This way, the user won't know where he went through. But it's strange why you want this hidden.

Comment: It's not strange at all! Look at the URL of this page, for instance :-)

Comment: Ah... Is that what you meant? :)
If you want the URLs to appear like in this page, you have to simply change your coding method. This method is called segmenting, as opposed to putting the file name with query strings.
This is a common thing if you have an OO model or MVC framework.
For ordinary coding I find this extra work, but that's me :)
For the first time I really used segments after starting Code Igniter - http://codeigniter.com.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="../dir/index.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="19">
    <select style="width: 60px;" name="number">
        <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="4">4</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" class="input_submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton">
</form>
```

assuming 'dir' directory is out side the directory of the file which contains this form.

Comment: Hi asprin. I don't want to include the file name in the url, because then the user would see 'x.php' in the url instead of just the directory. Your comments inspired me to start messing around with the URL and I discovered that appending a slash at the end of the action URL results in the data being POSTed, but no slash, no data. Why would that be?

Comment: I'm not sure I know the exact answer, but if you don't want users to see the filename in the address bar, you can remove the .php extension from 'x.php' so that to the user it would look like a directory '/x'. Look into URL rewriting using .htaccess if you are on a Linux server or URL rewriting using web.config if on a Windows server.